# How to put the value of a match function in an offseted cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns: I'm trying to loop through each one to find the word I put in the box. Following this, I want to write the respective row number in 
the cell two cells to the left from the current cell. The activecell.offset just keeps giving me zero and I can't figure out what's going wrong

```
The  jumps
quick   Over
brown   nine
fox   lazy
    dogs


Sub AddRow()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, HT As Variant, nr As Integer, nc As Integer, lrow As Integer, lrows As Variant, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, row As Integer, rows As Integer
    nr = Selection.rows.Count
    nc = Selection.Columns.Count
    HT = InputBox("Enter column letter:")
    Set rng1 = Range("E1:E100")
    Set rng2 = Range("F1:F100")
    For i = 1 To nr
        For j = 1 To nc
            If ActiveCell(i, j) = HT And ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
                 lrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HT, Range("E1:E200"), 0)

            Else
                If ActiveCell(i, j) = HT And ActiveCell.Column = 2 Then
                    lrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HT, Range("F1:F200"), 0)

                End If
                ActiveCell.Offset(0,2).Value = lrow
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use Range.Find method on the two columns and avoid the looping? And why work with Activecell? Can you not specify a target range or an offset from where value found (if found) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ranges instead.

QHarr's comment on your question is on track.

A Range represents a single cell or group of cells in an excel sheet, and it is the best way to address the cells in a worksheet.
You can address ranges by excel coordinates, eg. "A1" or by row number and column number.
Here is a quick example of getting a range, then using it to get information, or using it to move to other cells. 
I included the correct use of Offset().  You can see now why QHarr said to use ranges, because you need a Range object to make Offset() work.

...oh, and Range.Value2 gives the value in a cell.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub main()
    Dim HT As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
    Dim myNewRange As Range


    HT = InputBox("Enter column letter:")

    'range returns a cell
    Set myRange = Range(HT & "1")

    'get the column of the cell.
    ColumnNumber = myRange.Column
    MsgBox ColumnNumber

    'get the cell, one cell over and one cell down
    Set myNewRange = myRange.Offset(1, 1)
    MsgBox "My New Range is at " & myNewRange.Row & " - " & myNewRange.Column


End Sub
```